# Convert laravel Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel-5

Could your any one help me how i will convert like this query

```
SELECT * FROM prize_frequency WHERE SYSDATE() BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in laravel for given query:

```
DB::table('prize_frequency')
                ->whereRaw('SYSDATE() BETWEEN start_time AND end_time')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

RAW QUERY

```
DB::table('prize_frequency')->whereRaw('SYSDATE() BETWEEN start_time AND end_time')->get();
```

You can use eloquent for readable

Model:

PriceFrequency
 - start_time
 - end_time

`$priceFrequency = \App\PriceFrequency::where('start_time', '>=', now())->where('end_time', '<=', now())->get();`